# Excel: Merge two columns

Tags: excel, vba

How to merge this two columns :
[Original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQ9JW.png)

To one column:
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zIZAd.png)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This script is working

```
    Public Sub CullValues()
    Dim i&, j&, k&, v
    v = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    For i = 1 To UBound(v, 1)
        k = 0
        For j = 1 To UBound(v, 2)
            If Len(v(i, j)) Then
                k = k + 1
                v(i, k) = v(i, j)
                If j > k Then v(i, j) = Empty
            End If
        Next
    Next
    [a1].Resize(UBound(v, 1), UBound(v, 2)) = v
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

In **C1** enter:

```
=IF(A1&B1="","",IF(A1="",B1,A1))
```

and copy down.

This is a typical merge formula.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this statement:

```
Sheet1.UsedRange.Columns("A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Delete xlToLeft
```

You can do it either from the immediate pane or from inside any VBA routine.